# UIGraphicsImageContext leaks when backgrounded

Tags: ios, multithreading, uikit, memory-leaks

Supposedly the UIKit calls are thread safe as of iOS 4, but when I try to render a PDF page in a background thread and pulling out an image from the view, I get a ton of leaks. As soon as I put it in the foreground, it has zero leaks.

The code is pretty standard

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContext ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Flip the coordinate system
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, rect.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.f, -1.f);

// Transform coordinate system to match PDF
NSInteger rotationAngle = CGPDFPageGetRotationAngle(_page);
CGAffineTransform transform = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(_page, kCGPDFCropBox, rect, -rotationAngle, NO);
CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);

CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, _page);
UIImage *i = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

As said, 0 leaks on main thread, tons of leaks on background thread. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you created a `NSAutoReleasePool` for the bg thread?

Comment: Yep. I @autoreleasepool {} the whole thing.

Comment: *"Supposedly the UIKit calls are thread safe as of iOS 4"* -- only a handful were said to be safe in the release notes. certainly not all of them.

Comment: @justin: fair enough, but I checked every one that I use and all of them have the "thread safe as of iOS 4" disclaimer on them.

Comment: @Kalle right - i didn't see a problem in the sample, but i thought i'd just clarify that to avoid any confusion. if you don't find an answer, you can quite easily avoid using UIKit for this program -- just create your own CGBitmapContext and have it create a CGImage. that adds just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code, and it doesn't cause leaks.

The problem was that I had a retain cycle going on that was triggered when this code was triggered. Oddly enough, I didn't SEE the leak when these calls happened on the main thread, but I did see them when on the background thread.